# Exporting a three-dimensional graphic to EPS

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, export

I draw a three-dimensional graphic with the use of the command "Graphics3D". The graphic includs lots of solid and dashed lines. When exporting the graphic into the EPS format, the final figure builted through the LaTex has no the dashed line. What happended? The Mathematica version now is 11.0.

Comment: try to play with a curve thickness, may be it is too thin for good rendering

Comment: It is not recommended to export 3d graphics in vector format. Much better results can be achieved by using png or jpg. This seems paradoxical because vectors formats promise optimal resolution at any magnification, while pixel formats are rendered at fixed resolution. However, consider that one can always render the picture at optimal resolution (300dpi, maximum 600dpi for journal prints is sufficient, even smaller values for screen presentations).  Additionally: i) the size of jpg is several order of magnitude smaller than that of eps or pdf; 2) MS Word better works with pixel formats.

Comment: @Rom38 I have tried to modify the thickness of curves. But the curves are not clear. The way to export 3d graphics in jpg format may be well, as yarchik said.

Comment: @yarchik Thank you for your help. Your method works very well.